# Facebook Marketing/Insights API returns OAuthException with error code 100 missing permissions

Tags: python, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights, facebook-business-sdk

Lately, the Facebook Marketing API throws an OAuthException error with code 100/missing permissions. When looking into the Facebook Developer App, nothing indicates that the permissions are missing or not configured properly. The permissions needed for the Insights API (ads_read) is active and currently at Standard Access (which should be sufficient).

I've also validated my token with the Access Token debugger, but it's valid nonetheless. I am using the Python facebook-business SDK 12.0.1 to make the call to the Insights endpoint:

```
params = {
            'time_range': {'since' : self.time_range, 'until' : self.time_range},
            'breakdowns' : self.breakdowns,
            'fields': self.fields,
            'filtering' : self.filtering,
            'level': self.level,
            'limit' : self.limit          
        }     

response = my_account.get_insights(params=params)
```

The full error code:

```
Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{ad_account_id}/insights
  Params:  {'time_range': '{"since":"2021-10-28","until":"2021-10-28"}', 'breakdowns': '["publisher_platform","platform_position"]', 'fields': '["campaign_name","clicks","spend","impressions","date_start","campaign_id","adset_id","ad_id","adset_name","ad_name","link_url"]', 'filtering': '[{"field":"ad.impressions","operator":"GREATER_THAN","value":"0"}]', 'level': 'ad', 'limit': '100000'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Missing permissions",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AZhZZ3O_3iRkR4nObcyU-yB"
      }
    }
```

My current assumption is that something is wrong with the FB Marketing API. Or is it?

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue?

Comment: @Idhem Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: fwiw, I ran into this issue before I realized I was making a GET request when I meant to make a POST...

Comment: This error can also be caused by passing in an incorrectly formatted `ad_account_id`. The ID in the url should not contain the `act_` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I found this helpful re: the access token.
https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/issues/125

In my case I needed to use the **PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN** *instead* of the access_token acquired by hitting "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app_secret>&grant_type=client_credentials"

Of course this is clear as mud in facebook's documentation.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still get the same error as in my original post.